# How to serve both static HTML and assets on a CDN and have friendly URLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I am trying to setup a website whereby both the static HTML pages and assets are served by AWS cloudfront (CDN).
I would also like to have friendly/pretty URLs for my pages and therefore need to create a AWS lambda function to redirect the friendly/pretty URLs to the correct webpage.
Is this the only solution to my problem or is there a more eloquent way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Lambda@Edge is a feature of Cloudfront that allows you to run serverless functions to tweak the HTTP requests or responses between Cloudfront and your Origin or visitor. here is an [example](https://github.com/digital-sailors/standard-redirects-for-cloudfront)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an alias record in Route53 or if you have some other DNS provider to point to your CloudFront distribution.

Lambda@Edge is not meant for this.